# Getting error when sending mail to more than one address using SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: iphone

I am getting error when i am trying to send mail to more than one email address using AOL account in SKPSMTPMESSAGE api. I can send with one receiver but i can send to more than one receiver. Getting message like "To address rejected".

Does anyone has face this problem?.

Thanks,
iPhone Dev.

Comment: how are you adding the multiple addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding multiple receiver by to, cc, bcc, cc1, cc2... and then i am adding this address on smtpmessage class. It works fine with gmail, htmail but it doesn't work with AOL. I checked in original source code and i found that there is bug in original API, try to add bcc with Aol, you will get error.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your source code so that we can help answer your question?